# Prevent open activity after click home

Tags: android, android-launcher, app-launcher

I have the following scenario:

Activity A (Main Activity)

Activity B (Normal Activity)

**Normal activities**:Launcher App (Open A) then start Activity B

**Unusual operation**:Launcher App (Open A), quickly click Home before activity B is started, app go to background then Activity B open to foreground.

**Question: How can I make Activity B not open on foreground or only open when I come back?**

Comment: Why do you want to click Home button before Activity B comes to foreground? Could you be more spesific?

Comment: This is an example of starting activity in the background

Comment: On which step of the lifecycle are you starting Activity B?

Comment: I load data from database before start activity B